# Proving an inequality with the Markov inequality given a sequence of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\{R_{\epsilon}: \epsilon > 0\}\subset M_1(M_1(\Sigma))$ be a family of probability measures $ M_1(\Sigma)$ is the space of probability measures on the Polish space $\Sigma)$, such that it satisfies the following property for bounded and measurable $V: \Sigma \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, $$\left(\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\Sigma} Vd\nu\right]R_{\epsilon}(d\nu)\right)^{\epsilon}\leq M \int_{\Sigma} \exp[\beta V]d\mu.$$ Let $\delta > 0, M\in [1,\infty), \beta \in [1, \infty), T\in (0, \infty), \mu \in M_1(\Sigma).$ I need to prove the following inequality: $$R_{\epsilon}\left({\nu \in M_1(\Sigma): \int_{\Sigma} Vd\nu \geq \delta}\right)\leq \left(M e^{-T\delta} \int_{\Sigma}\exp[\beta TV]d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}, 0<\epsilon\leq 1.$$ First of all, I am not sure if the provided property of the family of measures is relevant in proving the inequality. In proving the inequality, it seems as if the Markov inequality may play a role. By Markov's inequality one gets: $$R_{\epsilon}\left(\nu \in M_1(\Sigma): \exp\left[\int_{\Sigma} Vd\nu \frac{T}{\epsilon}\right] \geq \exp\left[\delta\frac{T}{\epsilon}\right]\right)\leq \left(e^{-T\delta}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left[\int_{\Sigma} Vd\nu T\right]\right]\right)^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}.$$ I do not know how to go from here. I do not understand, which is the variable the expectation should take care of. In particular, I do not see why and how one would get the measure $\mu$ at the right hand side of the inequality. Can you provide some help ? Thanks.

Comment: hey again, I guess ^^ could you please clean up the formulas? It is very difficult to understand what is written there. I would suggest only putting the main formula and all the additional conditions are quantifiers in the text. Also, it is not clear to me, what $\in_\Sigma$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of solved this problem, even though not completely. But I just posted another question which is related to this one which concerns the logarithmic moment generating function under different measures. I will appreciate it if you get a look at that one.

Comment: it seems that you are working on a project and asking questions for each step of the way. Sometimes, it is worth taking some more time to ponder on these questions before asking them here. That avoids the problem of others thinking about problems that you'll solve anyway a bit later ;)